# Displaying the correct price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm struggling with the problem on this website (http://duledo.co.uk/product-category/self-healing-mat-cutting-mat/). I used WooCommerce Currency Switcher. The prices are updated except English version of this site. What's the problem with this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I guess your English language file is same as Polski language file. check for that. or try to reset this currency switcher again.

Comment: You can add some screen-shots to improve question

Comment: @MKGarwa: You're right! The lack of **en_EN.po** file, but when I tried installed new language in Loco Translate I received **"Error: Internal Server Error"**.

Comment: It means there is some syntax error in that file. open that file and check the before installing. or match the format with other language file.

Comment: @MKGarwa: I increased **wp_memory_limit** in wp-config.php and I could normally installed additional languages. In addition, I have received an error: **"Error: {"data":{"authed":true,"valid":[],"creds":[],"method":"direct","success":"Connected to remote file system. Check console output for debugging information."** I didn't created this site, but I think it's completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

Check woocommerce settings. There must be a tab name currency. Check the currency, symbol, price etc from one you have choosen to show under english language.

Even after this if you are getting this issue then you can also override plugin.

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.imgsafe.org/cb/cbd2f684eb.png)

In WooCommerce options I see only "polish zloty" currency. I see also that this site works on PHP in 5.3.29 version.

Comment: You might have any other plugin related to this. If so then disable that temporarily. There might be any conflict due to that.